# PeerJs call on stream function not working on safari iOS

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

Works fine on chrome mobile and PC.
But does not work on the iOS Safari browser does not even log the `connect to new user`

```
const call = myPeer.current.call(data.peerId, ownLocalStream.current);
call.on('stream', (incomingStreamCall: any) => {
 console.log(incomingStreamCall, 'connect to new user on');
 ...      
})
```

Using Peerjs library on reactjs typescript.